# C++ muestra valores distintos a los ingresados y saltea ingreso de dato

Tags: c++, variables

les comento, estoy haciendo una tara de la facultad y me encuentro con dos problemas que a continuación paso a detallar:
El primero es que al momento de tener que ingresar el apellido de la persona, se saltea el paso.
El segundo es que al momento de mostrar los datos ingresados, el numero de teléfono claramente no es nada que ver con el ingresado. Sin embargo el DNI si coincide con lo ingresado. 
Probé ingresar un numero que tenga menos de 10 dígitos (como pueden ver la variable del apellido, tiene una longitud máxima de 10 y pensé que eso podría estar "molestando") Y no tuve ninguno de los dos errores que detallé anteriormente. Ahora, si ingreso un verdadero numero de teléfono de mi zona que tienen 10 dígitos, el programa se saltea el paso de pedir el apellido y muestra un numero de teléfono totalmente diferente al ingresado. A continuación dejo foto del código y el programa ya compilado y ejecutado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad que esto me tiene bastante frustrado, hace 2 años programo en Python y C# y nunca me pasó esto y menos en algo tan básico como este tipo de problemas :/

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int dni;
    float height;
    int tel;
    char surname[10];

    cout << "Ingrese su DNI: ";
    cin >> dni;
    cout << "Ingrese su altura: ";
    cin >> height;
    cout << "Ingrese su numero de telefono: "; 
    cin >> tel;
    cout << "Ingrese su apellido: "; 
    cin >> surname;

    cout << "\nDatos ingresados:\nDNI: "<<dni<<"\nAltura: "<<height<<"\nNumero de telefono: "<<tel<<"\nApellido: "<<surname;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, no coloques es código como imagen. Nadie podrá copiarlo/pegarlo para reproducir tu problema y poder ayudarte.

Comment: Buen punto, gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El número de teléfono que introduces es el 5583951418. Si lo convertimos a binario obtenemos el número:

```
 |32  |28  |24  |20  |16  |12  |8   |4  
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
1|0100|1100|1101|0100|0101|0110|0011|1010
```

Que tiene 33 bits... y, cosas de la vida, el tipo `int` solo es capaz de almacenar 31 bits (reseva un bit para el signo).

Así pues en `teléfono` se almacena la parte que *cabe* en la variable, es decir, los primeros 32 bits:

```
1|0100 1100 1101 0100 0101 0110 0011 1010 --> telefono real
 |
 |0100 1100 1101 0100 0101 0110 0011 1010 --> Lo que cabe
```

Es facil entender que si le quitamos bits a un número, el valor del mismo va a cambiar.

Esto lo puedes solucionar facilmente cambiando el tipo de dato.

Si usas `long long` en vez de `int`, la variable tendrá 64 bits para almacenar el número. Más que de sobra para almacenar los 10 dígitos que pretendes.

Comment: Mientras esperaba alguna respuesta estuve googleando sobre los alcances de las variables en c++ y me encontré con el tipo de variable que mencionas, solo que tuve la suerte de entrar en una pagina donde nombra como "long int" y no como "long long" la verdad que Python me tiene mal acostumbrado con el tema de no tener que declarar el tipo de la variable jajaja. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.